# Mapping through a json array to render screen React Native

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, expo, antd

I have a json parsed array saved as a variable in the this.state portion of the constructor (saved as this.state.accordionarr). Then, I am trying to render an Accordion list(from ANTD Mobile RN). However, when I try to access this.state.accordionarr, I receive the TypeError undefined is not an object (evaluating this.state.accordionarr). However, I know the variable saved the correct json array with the console log. Here is my code:

This is the part where I make the array initially

```
if (this.state.idofdate != null && this.state.idofdate != undefined && this.state.idofdate != "") {
      db.collection('entirelog').doc(this.state.idofdate).collection('meals').get().then(querySnapshot => {
        const yourDocuments = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
        this.setState({
          accordionarr: yourDocuments
        });
        console.log(this.state.accordionarr);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        alert(err);
      });
    }
```

This is the console.log of this.state.accordionarr, which is correct. It is the parsed json that I want

```
Array [
  Object {
    "carbohydrate": 8,
    "id": 0,
    "name": "kimbap",
    "protein": 1111,
  },
  Object {
    "carbohydrate": 67,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "soup",
    "protein": 56,
  },
]
```

This is where I try to render and access the variable.

```
function renderAccordion() {
      return this.state.accordionarr.map((item,index) => {
        return(
          <View key={index}>
            <Accordion
              onChange={this.onChange}
              activeSections={this.state.activeSections}
            >
              <Accordion.Panel header= {item.name}>
                <List>
                  <List.Item>{item.protein}</List.Item>
                  <List.Item>{item.carbohydrate}</List.Item>
                </List>
              </Accordion.Panel>
            </Accordion>
          </View>
        );
      });
    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the state `accordionarr` is not defined on the first render or `this` it not accessible in the `renderAccordion` function. What do you see when you're logging `this.state.accordionarr` in `renderAccordion`?

Could you try to initialise  `accordionarr` with an empty array or change the first line in `renderAccordion` to:

`return this.state.accordionarr && this.state.accordionarr.map((item,index) => {`.


In case the component is still not rendering correctly it would help if you could show the complete accordion component.

Comment: i am stupid. thank you you are a god